# Buffered function to get line command parameters

Tags: java

I’m trying to run this code:

```
public static void main (String [] args )
{ 
   BufferedReader reader = 
              new BufferReader (); 
   
   String name = reader.readLine(); 

   System.out.println(“Hello ”name);
}
```

But I’m getting an error.

Comment: "I'm getting an error" doesn't provide us much useful information. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question, formatting your code appropriately as well. But where do you expect `new BufferedReader()` to get input from?

Comment: What error do you have? One of them is `System.out.println(“Hello ”name);`.  It should be something like this.  `System.out.println(“Hello ”+name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding the completed code for the Buffered function, as this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader reader = 
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = reader.readLine();

    System.out.println("Hello "+name);        
}
```

Comment: You probably want to catch exceptions in main.